# Gulp-postcss with precss plugin throws an error when importing scss files

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, postcss

Im trying to import multiple scss files in my app.scss file but gulp is throwing an error:

```
//app.scss
@import "base";

body {
   background: #fff;
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
    return gulp.src(assetsDev + 'scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(postcss([precss, autoprefixer, cssnano]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(ext_replace('.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(assetsProd + 'css/'));
});
```

Directory structure:

```
├── assets
│   └── scss
│       ├── _base.scss
│       └── app.scss
├── src
│   └── css
│       └── style.css
└── gulpfile.js
```

And gulp is throwing this error:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\assets\scss\_base.css'
at Error (native)
```

Comment: try @import "./_base";

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precss` uses the [`postcss-partial-import`](http://npmjs.com/package/postcss-partial-import) plugin for `@import` statements. [By default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-partial-import#extension) it assumes that the extension of imported partials is `css`.

You need to either provide the full file name (with extension) in all of your `@import` statements:

```
@import "_base.scss";

body {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Or you need to pass the `extension` option to `precss()`:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
  return gulp.src(assetsDev + 'scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss([precss({extension:'scss'}), autoprefixer, cssnano]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(ext_replace('.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(assetsProd + 'css/'));
});
```